# Does the tag wiki for reactjs violate copyright law or at least require identifying the source of the content?

Tags: discussion

I noticed the Stack Overflow [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/92497) for [reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs) is largely a direct copy of the text from https://reactjs.org which is copyrighted by Facebook, Inc.

The tag wiki does not indicate that it was largely copied from that copyrighted website.

Does this represent a copyright violation, and thus need to be changed by someone immediately?

If it's not a copyright violation, does the tag wiki at least need to be modified to make it clear that the text was copied from another source?

Comment: Advice on what to do when you encounter a plagiarized tag wiki is at the bottom of the FAQ answer.

Comment: @JeanneDark Thanks.  In accordance with the FAQ, I flagged a post with that tag for moderator review so the content of the tag wiki can be reviewed.

Comment: There is an edit suggestion on its tag excerpt that introduces meta-info with no usage guidance (which is not your fault, frankly, given it was absent before too), so sorry, had to click reject. Any fellow tag wiki/excerpt reviewer seeing this and wanting to restore balance to the force, please do drop by the tag

Comment: @OlegValter Thanks for your kind words Oleg.  If you're referring to the edit I proposed, no problem.  Although I don't mind it being rejected, I thought it was standard practice to accept edits that are deemed improvements, even if they don't fix all the issues.  Am I mistaken?  (Of course, if it's not an improvement at all, a rejection is always desired.)

Comment: Eh, kind of, I think - if you have a wiki edit pending, I will be glad to hit the approve button as it is an improvement for tag wikis. For excerpts, valuable additions are not who maintains something, but additional usage guidance, basically anything that makes it clearer what the rag is for rather than what it is (there is even a standard rejection reason for edits that expand on what something is rather than how to use it). If the edit is still pending, and you are willing to add some guidance, I'd be happy to have the decision overridden (I would even change the vote, but the system...

Comment: ...does not allow for such flexibility) by fellow reviewers. If you do not have a tag wiki edit submitted, then I urge you to do so (but consider if you can add something else to it too). Glad that I noticed it was your edit - usually reviewers can only communicate with suggestors via the ridiculously limited custom rejection reason or edit summaries (as you might know if you reviewed normal suggested edits before)